# sql export does not show in phpmyadmin version 4.8.4

Tags: phpmyadmin

phpmyadmin version 4.8.4
try to export a database table with format "sql". But sql is no longer in the format options as was in former versions. the default export format is set to sql...
if I export a database, sql option is showing.
What is wrong?

problem occurs on 2 servers independantly

Comment: **Fixed after 4.8.4 version, download latest version**.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that this is a bug, see Github. You must update your phpMyAdmin to 4.8.4.1 as soon as possible or add this on line 665 in libraries/classes/Display/Export.php:

```
// Export a single table
if (isset($_GET['single_table'])) {
    $GLOBALS['single_table'] = $_GET['single_table'];
}
```

[sql export does not show in phpmyadmin version 4.8.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54160989/sql-export-does-not-show-in-phpmyadmin-version-4-8-4/54169908#54169908)